Is the square consisting of $C(X \cup Y)$, $C(X)$, $C(Y)$ and $C(X \cap Y)$ both a pushout and pullback in $\mathsf{Ring}$?
Let $Z$ be a topological space and $X, Y \subseteq Z$ be subspaces.
What are the pushouts of the following diagram in $\mathsf{Ring}$?
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{array}{cc}
\begin{CD}
C(X \cup Y) @>>> C(X) \\
@VVV \\
C(Y)
\end{CD}
&
\begin{CD}
C_b(X \cup Y) @>>> C_b(X) \\
@VVV \\
C_b(Y)
\end{CD}
\end{array}
$$
In particular, do we have
$$
C(X) \otimes_{C(X \cup Y)} C(Y) \cong C(X \cap Y)
$$
and
$$
C_b(X) \otimes_{C_b(X \cup Y)} C_b(Y) \cong C_b(X \cap Y)
$$
?
Analogously, what are the pullbacks of the following diagrams in $\mathsf{Ring}$?
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{array}{cc}
\begin{CD}
@. C(X) \\
@. @VVV \\
C(Y) @>>> C(X \cap Y)
\end{CD}
&
\begin{CD}
@. C_b(X) \\
@. @VVV \\
C_b(Y) @>>> C_b(X \cap Y)
\end{CD}
\end{array}
$$
In particular, do we have
$$
C(X) \times_{C(X \cap Y)} C(Y) \cong C(X \cup Y)
$$
and
$$
C_b(X) \times_{C_b(X \cap Y)} C_b(Y) \cong C_b(X \cup Y)
$$
?

You probably want $X,Y$ to be open. Otherwise if $X$ is an open interval and $Y$ its complement in the real line then things fail spectacularly.

@Trebor Thanks. It seems like this condition is even sufficient.

Are you sure that you want to take the pushout in the category of rings? It is much nicer in the category of commutative rings, namely $C(X) \otimes_{C(X \cup Y)} C(Y)$. Bure surely neither is $C(X \cap Y)$.

@MartinBrandenburg For some reason I thought that taking the pushout in the category of rings would yield the same result as taking the pushout in the category of commutative rings, but of course this isn't true. Actually, I might even want to take the pushout in the category of commutative $\mathbb{R}$-algebras...

If $X$ and $Y$ are open in $X \cup Y$, we indeed have
$$
C(X) \times_{C(X \cap Y)} C(Y) \cong C(X \cup Y)
$$
and
$$
C_b(X) \times_{C_b(X \cap Y)} C_b(Y) \cong C_b(X \cup Y)
$$
Take any ring $R$ and any pair of ring homomorphisms $\varphi: R \to C(X)$, $\psi: R \to C(Y)$ with $\operatorname{res}_{X \cap Y \leftarrow X} \circ \varphi = \operatorname{res}_{X \cap Y \leftarrow Y} \circ \psi$. Given any $r \in R$, define $\chi(r): X \cup Y \to \mathbb{R}$ via $\chi(r) \big|_X = \varphi(r)$ and $\chi(r) \big|_X = \psi(r)$. By the commutativity assumption, this is well-defined as a set function. Additionally, since $X$ and $Y$ are open and $\chi(r)$ is continuous on each open set individually, it is in fact open on all of $X \cup Y$. Hence we obtain a ring homomorphism $R \to C(X \cup Y)$. This shows that $C(X) \times_{C(X \cap Y)} C(Y) \cong C(X \cup Y)$. The analogous proof works in the bounded case.
